# Appium error:Bad parameters: BadParametersError:..wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional": ["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]}

Tags: java, android, appium

My configuration:

```
Windows 10 64bit
appium 1.6.4
appium java-client-5.0.0-BETA7
android 5.1
```

Error messages:

```
 [debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were
 incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":
 ["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]} and you sent 
 ["capabilities","desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities"]
```

I checked the error message:

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were 
incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":
["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]} and you sent 
["capabilities","desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities"]
```

it seems that the sent parameter format

```
 {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]}
```

mismatched with wanted format,just like a version mismatching issue:

```
["capabilities","desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities"]
```

But same configuration (appium,java-client,android) works in ubuntu 16.04 64bit,

Comment: is it a maven project? can you please attach your .pom file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My "platformVersion" parameters didn't match the Android version of my testing device.

I used

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
```

whereas my device was in Android 6.0.1